# Sorting String array with different encoding

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, encoding, character-encoding

I have a request to sort array of Strings but not using default encoding. I need to convert it to "IBM500" to sort it, and to convert the result to default encoding and return it.

We already have a function in db that is doing that but we need to reimplement this with Java. I don't have much experience with encoding, so every hint or example would be great!

Comment: You are mixing concepts, or not telling the whole story; an encoding cannot determine the sorting order of strings (well, to be exact, when talking text, that should be the _collating_ order). Can you be more precise?

Comment: Would [Java comparator for String in EBCDIC encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525015/java-comparator-for-string-in-ebcdic-encoding) work for you (using `IBM500` instead of `IBM1047` as the encoding)?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Mick, this is exactly what I need. Please add it as answer so I can accept it!