# Implement EBCDIC Sorting in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

I have a List of maps with key(String) and Value(Object), the requirement is to sort the list as EBCDIC sort not as a java sort. Anyone aware of any custom code already there or any pointers to start the  custom sort coding in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of map"? Is it a list, or is it a map? You could use a `TreeMap` with a custom comparer, at which point you're really down to just writing the custom comparer - if your question is just "How do I compare strings using EBCDIC instead of Java" it becomes a bit simpler, or at least better-defined.

Comment: did you tries custom comparator using charset? may b this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525015/java-comparator-for-string-in-ebcdic-encoding could help you.

Comment: @OAD i looked in to that but no idea how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the strings to bytes in the EBCDIC Charset.

Note that byte has a range of -128 to 127.  Characters higher than 127 will be negative so they don't compare properly to the positive bytes. To handle that convert the EBCDIC bytes back to Strings in the default Charset and then compare them.

Example:

```
Charset ebcdicCharset = Charset.forName("IBM037");
Comparator<String> ebcdicComparator = Comparator.comparing(
    value -> new String(value.getBytes(ebcdicCharset)));
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott, for the clear and concise code for a good comparator for EBCDIC, useful on any Collection object that provides a sort ability.